distance of detected object to the ground?
I want to know the distance from a robot detected object to the ground in meters.
The robot sees an image in which a detected object dimensions are evaluated and eventually stored.
If the image is strictly perpendiculaire to the robot (NAO) sight (case 1) in the attached image) then we can adjust to the height of the object and tell the distance to the ground by centering the object in the image and measuring the distance from the eyes of the robot to the ground (correct me here as well if I am wrong).

if the robot sees the image with a certain angle (say x) then what would be the formula evaluating the distance to the ground (to note that the distance from the  object to the robot is known so I suppose a tangent equation here would do it) ?

For the perpendicular view:
$D_{\text{ground}} = h_{\text{robot}} - h_{\text{object}}
$
For the angled view:
$D_{\text{ground}} = h_{\text{robot}} - (d_{\text{robot-object}} \cdot \tan(x))
$
Where:

$h_{\text{robot}}$ = Height of the robot’s camera from the ground
$h_{\text{object}}$ = Height of the object
$d_{\text{robot-object}}$ = Horizontal distance between the robot and the object
$x$ = Angle of depression from the robot's camera to the object


but what about the position of the object in the image itself? doesn't it necessary to include it in the calculation ? what if the object is at the right end of the image and not the center of it?
